# iOS In App Purchase - Different products in auto-renewing subscriptions

Tags: ios

I'm trying to integrate auto-renewing subscriptions in my app, a VoIp service. But I have a very important question. So it would be great if any of you can help!

I want to offer 4 types of auto-renewing products (S, M,L, XL). Each one of them include more minutes to call and features, and the user must have just 1 one contracted at any time. I cannot define them as items in the same family because the duration is the same (1 month). So, if I'm right, I must define them as different families.

How I handle then in the app to programatically cancel an autorenewing product (M for example) if the user wants to upgrade to L?

I cannot find a way to do it.

Thanks,

Marc

Answer (score 0):

You can not use this type of subscriptions in your case.

> Auto-renewable subscriptions allow users to purchase dynamic content, such as magazine subscriptions, for a set duration of time. Subscriptions renew automatically unless the user opts out of the renewal. If the content you want offer doesn’t fit what’s outlined in the App Review Guidelines, consider offering the content through a non-renewing subscription.
>   Auto-renewable subscriptions can include an incentive to customers who share their contact information with you.

[Link to apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html)

You would be the best use of Non-Consumable in-app purchase type.